# What is the use of the Void* in pointers

Tags: c++, pointers

I am unable to understand the use of (void*) in this pointer code.

```
std::cout<< "address character = " << (void *) &givenChar<<"\n\n";
```

Answer (score 4):

First of all you need to know what the address-of operator `&` does. For `&givenChar` it returns a pointer to the variable `givenChar`. Assuming (by its name) that `givenChar` is of type `char`, then `&givenChar` will be of type `char*`.

When using the formatted output operator `<<` passing `char*` will treat the pointer as the pointer to the first character of a zero-terminated string and will print that string. If you want to print the actual *pointer* (instead of the string it points to) then you need to convert the pointer to a generic untyped pointer, which have the type `void*`.

And that's the reason for the [*cast*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast): To be able to print the actual pointer to a character.

Answer (score 2):

You do not inform us what is type of `givenChar`. From the name it must be `char`. In this case type of the expression `&givenChar` is `char*`. If you would use it as is then overloaded stream operator with parameter of type `const char*` would be chosen, that is treated as a pointer to C null-terminated string. It is not true since `&givenChar` is a pointer to a single char and causes undefined behavior. The expression `(void *) &givenChar` forces a compiler to choose overloaded stream operator with the parameter type `const void*` that will print address contained in the pointer.

Answer (score 1):

A void pointer is just a variable which stores any memory address. A pointer value is just a memory address. All memory addresses are a certain size, so let us have a universal data type which is able to store the address of any object.

`&givenChar` returns the memory address where the variable `givenChar` is located. If the data type of the variable is `char`, then the returned memory address has a data type of `char*`. Then we typecast that `char*` value into a `void*` data type. Then the result of that type conversion is printed to the screen.

If you have a `char*` value, you can dereference it to get the `char` to which it points to. It is easy to remember: dereference "knocks off" a star `*`. However, since `void*` can store the memory address of any data type, we can't dereference it because we don't know if the value was previously a `char*` or a `int*`, or even a `std::string*` before it got converted into the `void*`. This is important because different data types have different sizes and different representations in memory. That's why we can't dereference a `void*`, we just don't know what it once pointed to.

Answer (score 0):

Here in this case it is needed to print address of the character thats why `&givenChar` is used to get the address of `givenChar`. Again it is casted to `(void *)`, so that appropriate overload is called to print address and not consider it as a `char*` to `Null` terminated string.

---

Also if we look deeper in to it, A pointer to `void` is a "generic" pointer type. A `void *` can be converted to any other pointer type without an explicit cast. You cannot dereference a `void *` or do pointer arithmetic with it; you must convert it to a pointer to an complete data type first.

It gets used in places where you need to be able to work with different pointer types in the same code. One commonly cited example is the library function `qsort`:

```
void qsort(void *base, size_t nmemb, size_t size, 
           int (*compar)(const void *, const void *));
```

`base` is the address of an array, `nmemb` is the number of elements in the array, `size` is the size of each element, and `compar` is a pointer to a function that compares two elements of the array. It gets called like so:

```
int iArr[10];
double dArr[30];
long lArr[50];
...
qsort(iArr, sizeof iArr/sizeof iArr[0], sizeof iArr[0], compareInt);
qsort(dArr, sizeof dArr/sizeof dArr[0], sizeof dArr[0], compareDouble);
qsort(lArr, sizeof lArr/sizeof lArr[0], sizeof lArr[0], compareLong);
```

The array expressions `iArr, dArr, and lArr` are implicitly converted from array types to pointer types in the function call, and each is implicitly converted from "pointer to `int/double/long`" to "pointer to `void`".

The comparison functions would look something like:

```
int compareInt(const void *lhs, const void *rhs)
{
  const int *x = lhs;  // convert void * to int * by assignment
  const int *y = rhs;

  if (*x > *y) return 1;
  if (*x == *y) return 0;
  return -1;
}
```

By accepting `void *`, `qsort` can work with arrays of any type.

The disadvantage of using void * is that you throw type safety out the window and into oncoming traffic. There's nothing to protect you from using the wrong comparison routine:

```
qsort(dArr, sizeof dArr/sizeof dArr[0], sizeof dArr[0], compareInt);
```

`compareInt` is expecting its arguments to be pointing to `int`s, but is actually working with `double`s. There's no way to catch this problem at compile time; you'll just wind up with a mis-sorted array.

Comment: can you please also tell the cause of error Stack Smashing Detected/ solution Terminated

Comment: It means that you wrote to some variables on the stack in an illegal way, most likely as the result of a Buffer overflow.

In your case probably you have not allocated any memory for the pointer variable 'givenChar'.

Please change the line where you declare this pointer variable. It should be like :

char* givenChar = new char;